# How to make preview like this on Google

Tags: seo

I know Google rich snippet and schema data. But i don't know like this.

**Q1**: Google recognize automatically or Web developer declare it in meta data?

**Q2**: What do we call it?

**Q3**: Is it payed service for any keyword combination?

[image]

**Another one**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not under your control. Google decides alone. There is no paid service for that.

The best you can do is make your site popular and very trustworthy in the eyes of Google, then cross your fingers and pray that they pick one of your pages.